# Android Studio - Gradle sync

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk

I'm experiencing the repository problem. I have just opened a new project, it now struck me that there's repository problem and that gradle didn't sync after it has completed loading. Please can someone help me out?

Comment: Please show error message/log, we don't know the solution if we don't even know what the problem is.

Comment: `repository problem` then you need to fix it. Sorry for obvious statement, but nothing more to say